# Cannot modify my handcoded SVG with Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I've handcoded a logo for my website with SVG markup in a text editor: https://codepen.io/Deka87/pen/LQzgrz?editors=1000.

I saved its contents in a brand.svg file and tried to open it with Illustrator to save as a PNG image. I got no error messages (e.g. those that the svg is not valid), however it appeared as a blank white image there.

Is there anything I missed while handcoding the SVG? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not seem to work right on firefox ESR, or Inkscape either so im having a bit hard time deciding what it should look like. IE renders the image as:

[image]

Is this correct?

Your code is **not valid** according to W3C validator.

For starters you need to write svg 1.1 code since that is what you say you are doing. there is no such tag as `def` it should be `defs`. So you can not use `href` atributes in `<use>` tags you need to use `xlink:href` instead. If you do this you get into illustrator but the thinsg have wrong size (still dont work in inkscape though).

Second, you can not rely on CSS to style all your needs because illustrator won't support all CSS that a browser would. For example neither Firefox does noyt seem to do `letter-spacing` and illustrator wont do `text-transform` etc.

Anyway illustrator is not a SVG editor as such, and tends to not work well with handcrafted svg. But the fact that even inkscape 0.92 throws you off means you have serious problems.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough comment! IE renders it right. I have serious problems indeed as I only tested this in Chrome. While def -> defs seems something that is easy to fix, I need to check other points as well. Thanks again!

Comment: Just a quick update. I had to remove the commas to make the image appear as needed on Firefox and other browsers it didn't for in.

Comment: @Deka87 i noticed that though i think it was not because of comma but missing space. There may be a bug in illustrator though on the symbols

Comment: Removing commas and replacing def with defs fixed the view in other browsers, however Illustrator keeps showing a black circle anyway. SVG to PNG converters give me a black rectange for some reason too. I will keep on investigating this.

Comment: Illustrator at least the newest one will make the other elements if you change href to xlink:href (as the standard of 1.1 demands) ithey will just be the wrong size, its like illustrator defaults to width and height 100%

Comment: In fact, this is weird. I try to open something as simple as:
```
<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <defs>
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" fill="red" id="circle"></circle>
 </defs>
 <use xlink:href="#circle" x="50" y="50"></use>
</svg>
```
with Inkscape but it shows me a blank page too. defs and use are not allowed in inkscape?

Comment: Ok, solved the issue on the inkscape chat. i should have used xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" together with xlink:href!